# Stream error while insertion into firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Stack permission denied :description:permission denied:cause null.

I want to insert data into firestore but this error occurs although rules are already allow.
So how to solve this when ever i want to add this stream permission denied error occur any faced please help me